# C# Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})

Tags: c#, json, serialization, response

I'm trying to deserialize a JSON response, I have searched alot for this and I know there are alot of posts about this, none of them witch worked.

Below you will see the JSON response:

```
{
"id": "xxx",
"name": "xxx",
"value": 138000,
"type": "sales",
"tags": "",
"external_id": "xxx",
"external_client_id": "api",
"external_editor_type": "",
"external_editor_id": "",
"company_name": "",
"company_number": "",
"company_id": "",
"company_logo_url": "",
"unique_id": 0,
"is_selfsign": true,
"is_signing_biometric": true,
"is_signing_initials": false,
"is_signing_forward": true,
"is_identify_recipient": false,
"is_private": false,
"status": "signed",
"send_date": "2020-08-14T09:46:04+00:00",
"sign_date": "2020-08-16T19:51:30+00:00",
"created_at": "2020-08-14T09:45:21+00:00",
"user_id": "9n6kgd3p",
"sender_name": "xxx",
"sender_thumb_url": "",
"sender_email": "xxx",
"email_send_template_id": "xxx",
"parent_id": "",
"email_send_subject": "xxx",
"email_send_message": "xxx",
"is_signing": true,
"is_signing_order": false,
"is_signed": true,
"expiration_date": "2020-08-28T21:59:00+00:00",
"is_scheduled_sending": false,
"scheduled_sending_time": null,
"is_reminder_sending": false,
"is_video": false,
"video_id": null,
"is_auto_comment": false,
"auto_comment_text": "",
"is_auto_comment_email": false,
"auto_comment_email": "",
"entity_auto_comment_text": "",
"field_count": 0,
"contract_start_date": null,
"contract_end_date": null,
"thumb_url": "xxx",
"preview_url": "xxx",
"download_url": "xxx",
"recipients": [
    {
        "fullname": "xxx",
        "first_name": "xxx",
        "last_name": "xxx",
        "email": "xxx",
        "title": "",
        "note": "",
        "gender": "m",
        "mobile": "",
        "thumb_url": "",
        "role": "signer",
        "company_name": "",
        "company_number": "",
        "status": "signed",
        "order_num": "1"
    }
]
```

}

And the classes I'm using:

```
public class Recipient
{
    public string fullname { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string note { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
    public string mobile { get; set; }
    public string thumb_url { get; set; }
    public string role { get; set; }
    public string company_name { get; set; }
    public string company_number { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string order_num { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string tags { get; set; }
    public string external_id { get; set; }
    public string external_client_id { get; set; }
    public string external_editor_type { get; set; }
    public string external_editor_id { get; set; }
    public string company_name { get; set; }
    public string company_number { get; set; }
    public string company_id { get; set; }
    public string company_logo_url { get; set; }
    public int unique_id { get; set; }
    public bool is_selfsign { get; set; }
    public bool is_signing_biometric { get; set; }
    public bool is_signing_initials { get; set; }
    public bool is_signing_forward { get; set; }
    public bool is_identify_recipient { get; set; }
    public bool is_private { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public DateTime send_date { get; set; }
    public DateTime sign_date { get; set; }
    public DateTime created_at { get; set; }
    public string user_id { get; set; }
    public string sender_name { get; set; }
    public string sender_thumb_url { get; set; }
    public string sender_email { get; set; }
    public string email_send_template_id { get; set; }
    public string parent_id { get; set; }
    public string email_send_subject { get; set; }
    public string email_send_message { get; set; }
    public bool is_signing { get; set; }
    public bool is_signing_order { get; set; }
    public bool is_signed { get; set; }
    public DateTime expiration_date { get; set; }
    public bool is_scheduled_sending { get; set; }
    public object scheduled_sending_time { get; set; }
    public bool is_reminder_sending { get; set; }
    public bool is_video { get; set; }
    public object video_id { get; set; }
    public bool is_auto_comment { get; set; }
    public string auto_comment_text { get; set; }
    public bool is_auto_comment_email { get; set; }
    public string auto_comment_email { get; set; }
    public string entity_auto_comment_text { get; set; }
    public int field_count { get; set; }
    public object contract_start_date { get; set; }
    public object contract_end_date { get; set; }
    public string thumb_url { get; set; }
    public string preview_url { get; set; }
    public string download_url { get; set; }
    public List<Recipient> recipients { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to deserialize it like this

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Root>>(response.Content);
email_send_message = data[0].email_send_subject;
Console.WriteLine(email_send_subject + " " + email_send_message);
```

I'm getting this error:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TelerikWinFormsApp1.GetAcceptAPI+DownloadSignedDocument+Root]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong, or atleast point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are deserialising into a `List<Root>` when your JSON only contains a `Root`, try this:  `var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(response.Content);`. the error message literally tells you this exact solution.

Comment: @DavidG This is the same solution Sowmyadhar Gourishetty suggested and it does not work, it results in an empty string even though the property has a value

Comment: What exactly is an empty string? I have tested the deserialisation and it works fine. Your output line is weird though. What is the `email_send_subject` variable?

Comment: Also, you missed the final `}` from your JSON.

Comment: @DavidG the 'email_send_subject ' is the subject of and email, witch has a value, but when I follow this solution, it does not output any value

Comment: Yes, but your code takes the subject and puts it in the message variable, then appends it to the subject again.

Comment: @DavidG Please, then tell, when I follow your solution, how would I output the variable in the console?

Comment: Here it is running... https://dotnetfiddle.net/QZHXV6

Comment: I see you modified the actual respone... Adding a '}' after the ']'... This is not the response I'm getting

Comment: Then the JSON is not valid and its absolutely not possible that you saw the error that you did.

Comment: Look, I'm looking at it right now... And modifying the response is not a solution since the response comes from an external partner. So that's the reality

Comment: If the JSON you posted here was valid, then you wouldn't have an empty string, you would have an exception. That's all I have to say on this question, good luck finding your answer,

Answer (score 2):

Update this

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Root>>(response.Content);
email_send_message = data[0].email_send_subject;
Console.WriteLine(email_send_subject + " " + email_send_message);
```

to

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(response.Content);
string subject = data.email_send_subject;
string message = data.email_send_message;
Console.WriteLine(subject + " " + message);
```

Your Json object is of single object but you are trying to deserialize to List which is wrong

Comment: I already tried this, when I try to write it into the console like this, and the result is an empty string

Comment: Does your JSON have values for those properties?

Comment: Can you have a debugger before you console your output and quick watch `data` to see its properties and values and also once do `Console.WriteLine(response.Content)`

Comment: I posted the whole JSON response in the question, you can see the value there (xxx)

Comment: The logic should work fine, then there is something else which is causing the issue, I did few more changes to the answer, can you please try that once again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219985/discussion-between-sowmyadhar-gourishetty-and-taco2).

Answer (score -2):

How about using JsonSerializer.Deserialize<>(response.Content)

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Also, your code is identical to the existing answer.

Comment: Take a closer look.

Comment: What exactly do you want me to look at?

Comment: JsonSerializer  and not JsonConvert

Comment: In that case, your answer is even worse because OP is using JSON.Net.

Comment: really?  https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm

Comment: Yes, if you use the `JsonSerializer` static class, it must be .NET Core and `System.Text.Json` namespace. Otherwise you need to instantiate a new `JsonSerializer` which you haven't shown.